# How do I make the background of a component transparent in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, button, components, transparent

How can I make the background of the Button component transparent in actionscript (or remove it completely) ?

I'd like to show a Button component with only the text label, no background, no border.

ps. I'm using AS2

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do that, since it is a ready-made component. Why not make a MovieClip and use Mouse Events?

Comment: Well this could be done easily with a clip yes, but I need to use components in this case, mainly because I need the whole form (i'm making a web form) to be browsable by keyboard with Tab, and this behavior is included by default with components.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a MovieClip-style button. They have tab access too.

Comment: Yes that would work for buttons, and that was actually my first option, but the form also has combo boxes (dropdown menus) and check boxes. Instread of going through the pain of doing all that "by hand", I prefer the facility and flexibility of the UI components provided by Flash.